# All my AWS datapipelines have stopped working with Validation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I use AWS data pipelines to automatically back up dynamodb tables to S3 on a weekly basis.
All of my data-pipelines, have stopped working since two weeks ago.

After some investigation, I see that EMR fails with "validation error" and "Terminated with errors No active keys found for user account". As a results all the jobs timeout.

Any ideas what this means?
I ruled out changes to the list of instant types that are allowed to be used with EMR.
Also I tried to read the EMR logs but it looks like it doesn't event get to the point to create logs (or I am looking for them in the wrong place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS account which used to launch EMR has keys ( access key and sec key ) Could you check if those keys are deleted ? You need to login to AWS console and check keys exists for your account.

if not re create keys and use in your code that launches EMR.

Answer (score 0):

Basically @Sandesh Deshmane answered my question correctly.

For future reference and clarity I explain the situation here too:

What happened was that originally I used the root account and console to create the pipelines.   Later I decided to follow the best practices and removed my root account keys.
A few days later (my pipelines are scheduled to run weekly) when they all failed I did not make the connection and thought of other problems.

I think one good way to avoid this (if you want to use console) will be to login to console with an IAM account and create the pipelines.
Or you can use command line tools to create them with and IAM credentials.

The real solution now (I think it was not available when the console was first introduced), is to assign the correct IAM role in the first page when you are creating your pipeline in the console. In the "security/access" section change it from default to custom and select the correct roles there.